# Read the file from local directory and change the colors of the row of HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In the below code, I am selecting file (say result.txt) using browse button from the local disk and reading it and displaying the contents on my HTML page. Also I have iterated the value to read the **1-5 lines of the file**.

I have one table with 2 rows `machine1` and `machine2`.

In the file I selected there is a variable present in the content  say :-

**machine1** = machine1 is **up** or machine 1 is **down.**

**machine2** = machine2 is **up** or machine 2 is **down**.

Can anyone suggest me how can I add a  condition in my below code so that it can read this value up and down from the result.txt file content and change the color of the respective rows as **red (for down)** and **green (for up)**?

**P.S:** Please copy my present code in a .txt file (say test.txt) and save it as test.html and open in IE or Firefox.

**MY CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" width="30%">
<tr>
  <td>machine1</td>
  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>machine2</td>
  
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
<hr size="2">
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range { margin-top: 5px; }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
    <button>Complete file</button>
    <button data-startbyte="0" data-endbyte="4">1-5</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>

<script>
  function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
        document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = 
            ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
             ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
      }
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

**RESULT.TXT**

```
Service1 =  replication job is working fine
Service2 = replaication job is working fine

machine1 = machine1 is up or machine 1 is down.

machine2 = machine2 is up or machine 2 is down.
```

Comment: If possible, can post `results.txt` , or how `machine1` and `machine2` variables appear as text within file ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 : I pasted the result.txt in my original post with the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Structure relevant data at `results.txt` as `json` string, e.g., beginning file with

```
{"Service1":"Replication job is working fine","Service2":"Replication job is working fine","machine1":"up","machine2":"down"}
```

- without spaces - should be first 123 to 127 bytes of `results.txt` , depending on `"up"` or `"down"` properties. Alternatively, could place data into distinct file, so as not to have to calculate where `json` string ends within file; entire file could be `json` `object` to be processed, irrespective of `blob.size`, or `length` of `json` string.

Then can process data as `json` , or `object`, i.e.g.,

html

```
<!-- data-* attribute utilized as `file`, or `results.txt` at jsfiddle -->
<data data-status='{"Service1":"Replication job is working fine","Service2":"Replication job is working fine","machine1":"up","machine2":"down"}'>machine data</data>
<br />
<table border="1" width="30%">
    <tr id="machine1">
        <td>machine1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="machine2">
        <td>machine2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    var blob = new Blob([$("data")[0].dataset.status], {
        "type": "application/json"
    });
    console.log(blob.size);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        if (e.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
            var status = $.extend({}, JSON.parse(e.target.result));

            if (status.machine1 === "up") {
                $("#machine1").css("color", "green")
            } else {
                $("#machine1").css("color", "red")
            };

            if (status.machine2 === "up") {
                $("#machine2").css("color", "green")
            } else {
                $("#machine2").css("color", "red")
            };

        };
    };
    reader.readAsText(blob);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8Pzp8/

Edit

fwiw, utilizing `json` formatted string (data structure), could achieve same result with `$.getJSON()`

`machines.json` :

```
                     { 
                      "Service1" : "Replication job is working fine",
                      "Service2" : "Replication job is working fine",
                      "machine1" : "up",
                      "machine2" : "down"
                     }
```

js

```
$.getJSON("machines.json", function(json, textStatus, jqxhr) {
              if (textStatus === "success" && jqxhr.responseJSON) {
                if (json.machine1 === "up") {
                    $("#machine1").css("color", "green")
                } else {
                    $("#machine1").css("color", "red")
                };

                if (json.machine2 === "up") {
                    $("#machine2").css("color", "green")
                } else {
                    $("#machine2").css("color", "red")
                };
              };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/4uN2y/